# How do I remove a percentage sign and find the average of some values in a column using r?

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a column in a dataset called `debt_to_income_ratio`.  The first six values in the column look like this:

```
1. 45
2. 43
3. 20%-<30%
4. 38
5. 49
6. 50%-60%
```

I have been trying to remove the percentage sign from the values that are percentages.  I have also been trying to find the mean of the values that are like 20%-<30% or like 50%-60%.  I would like them to read 25 and 55.
I used this code to try to remove the percentage sign, but it didn't work:

```
mutate(debt_to_income_ratio = gsub('//%','',debt_to_income_ratio))
```

I also am not sure how to find the average of only certain values in a column.  Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is one possibility using `map` from the `purrr` package and `str_extract_all` from the `stringr` package:

```
library(tidyverse)

mydata %>%
  mutate(debt_to_income_ratio = map_dbl(debt_to_income_ratio,
                                        ~mean(as.numeric(str_extract_all(.x, "\\d+")[[1]]))))
```

Here is the data I used:

```
mydata <- tibble(debt_to_income_ratio = c("45", "43", "20%<30%", "38", "49", "50%<60%"))
```

Answer (score 3):

A tidyverse option with your data

```r
  debt_to_income_ratio <- data.frame(mycol = c("45", "43", "20%-<30%", "38", "49", "50%-60%"))
  
  library(dplyr)
  library(stringr)
  
  debt_to_income_ratio <- debt_to_income_ratio %>% 
    mutate(
      newmycol = str_extract_all(mycol, "[0-9]+") %>%
        purrr::map( 
          ~ifelse(
            length(.x) == 1, 
            as.numeric(.x), 
            mean(unlist(as.numeric(.x)))
          )
        )
    )
  debt_to_income_ratio
#>      mycol newmycol
#> 1       45       45
#> 2       43       43
#> 3 20%-<30%       25
#> 4       38       38
#> 5       49       49
#> 6  50%-60%       55
```

Answer (score 3):

We could also use `rowMeans` with `extract`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
debt_to_income_ratio %>% 
  extract(mycol, into = c('col1', 'col2'), "^(\\d+)\\D*(\\d*).*", convert = TRUE) %>% 
   transmute(mycol = rowMeans(., na.rm = TRUE))
#  mycol
#1    45
#2    43
#3    25
#4    38
#5    49
#6    55
```

#### data

```
debt_to_income_ratio <- structure(list(mycol = c("45", "43", "20%-<30%", "38", "49", 
"50%-60%")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a `base R` solution:

```
extracted <- regmatches(df$debt_to_income_ratio, gregexpr("\\d+", df$debt_to_income_ratio))
df$debt_to_income_ratio <- sapply(extracted, function(x) mean(as.numeric(x)))

  debt_to_income_ratio
1                   45
2                   43
3                   25
4                   38
5                   49
6                   55
```

---

Data:

```
df <- data.frame(debt_to_income_ratio = c(45,43,"20%-<30%",38,49,"50%-60%"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a `base R`solution

```
debt_to_income_ratio$mean <- unlist(lapply(lapply(strsplit(sub("(\\d+)%-<?(\\d+)%", "\\1 \\2", debt_to_income_ratio$mycol), " "), as.numeric), mean))
```

Or, somewhat shorter:

```
library(stringr)
debt_to_income_ratio$mean <- unlist(lapply(lapply(str_extract_all(debt_to_income_ratio$mycol, "\\d+"), as.numeric), mean))
```

Result:

```
debt_to_income_ratio
     mycol mean
1       45   45
2       43   43
3 20%-<30%   25
4       38   38
5       49   49
6  50%-60%   55
```

Comment: You can simplify this slightly by replacing `unlist(lapply` with `sapply`. And like my answer, I prefer to use custom funcition in `sapply` rather than wrap multiple `lapply`.  `sapply(strsplit(sub("(\\d+)%-<?(\\d+)%", "\\1 \\2", debt_to_income_ratio$mycol), " "), function(x) mean(as.numeric(x)))`